# Date difference coming out to be wrong - Python

Tags: python, pandas, date, date-difference

I had date values in two formats (6/13/2018 and 6-13-2018). I had to calculate date difference. Below is my working.

Question: Number of days are coming out to be incorrect for few items.

```
X['Date of Closing'] = X['Date of Closing'].str.replace('/','-')
X['Date of First Contact'] = X['Date of First Contact'].str.replace('/','-')

X['Date Difference'] = (pd.to_datetime(X['Date of Closing'])- pd.to_datetime(X['Date of First Contact'])).dt.days
```

Example:

```
Date of First Contact  | Date of Giving Proposal  | Date of Closing  \
0             13-01-2014              26-02-2014      26-02-2014   
1             28-01-2014                2/2/2014        2-2-2014   
2              11-1-2014              26-01-2014      26-01-2014   
3             18-01-2014              18-01-2014      18-01-2014   
4             14-01-2014              14-01-2014      14-01-2014   
5               5-1-2014              14-01-2014      14-01-2014
```

Output:

> 44 - Correct
>
> 5 - Correct
>
> -279 - Incorrect
>
> 0 - Correct
>
> 0 - Correct
>
> -107 - Incorrect

Comment: You may need to pass `day_first=True` to `pd.to_datetime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need parameter `dayfirst=True` or `format`:

```
X['Date Difference'] = (pd.to_datetime(X['Date of Closing'], dayfirst=True)- 
                        pd.to_datetime(X['Date of First Contact'], dayfirst=True)).dt.days
```

---

```
X['Date Difference'] = (pd.to_datetime(X['Date of Closing'], format='%d-%m-%Y')- 
                        pd.to_datetime(X['Date of First Contact'], format='%d-%m-%Y')).dt.days
```

---

```
print (X)
  Date of First Contact Date of Giving Proposal Date of Closing  \
0            13-01-2014              26-02-2014      26-02-2014   
1            28-01-2014                2/2/2014        2-2-2014   
2             11-1-2014              26-01-2014      26-01-2014   
3            18-01-2014              18-01-2014      18-01-2014   
4            14-01-2014              14-01-2014      14-01-2014   
5              5-1-2014              14-01-2014      14-01-2014   

   Date Difference  
0               44  
1                5  
2               15  
3                0  
4                0  
5                9
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.